# Relative path in Batch File using %~dp0

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd

Is the following the correct way to reference relative paths in a Batch file:

```
if "%1" == "cd" ( 
pushd %~dp0
cd/
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\Test Studio\Bin"
ArtOfTest.Runner.exe list= "%~dp0TestListsCommunicator.aiilist" root="%~dp0"   settings="%~dp0SettingsForCD.xml"
popd
)
```

I am getting an error while running this batch file. If this is not the correct way kindly suggest the correct one. Thanks!

The error displayed is

```
Error: unrecognized or incomplete command line.
Unsupported argument ''!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArtOfTest.Runner.exe` is producing that error.

Try replacing `ArtOfTest.Runner.exe` with `echo(` to see precisely the arguments being passed.

I suspect that the space after `list=` may be your problem, but I've no idea what `ArtOfTest.Runner.exe` is or what it expects.

Comment: Turns out the space was causing the error plus I modified the root. It should be root="%~dp0\" to point to the correct folder. Rest is good. ArtOfTest.Runner is a telerik test studio product used for testing UI related components. The parameters for the exe are correct and in place. Do you know the significance of the code pushd%~dp0 & popd. Saw in an answer for a related question in SO. After researching on the internet could not find a correct example to what I have asked so thought of putting it myself.

Comment: PUSHD` pushes the current directory to `CMD`'s stack and switches to the target directory in the argument. `POPD` restores the prior directory from the stack. `%~dp0` means the drive(d) and path(p) from `%0`. The `~` removes quotes. `%0` is the 0th parameter to the batch, which is the batch name itself.

Comment: So I guess pushd here, is of no use as for me there is no need to switch to target directory. I am setting the path for artOfTest.runner.exe manually using cd. Correct?

Comment: True. And I've included a small error in my desription of `~`. It is required to indicate that the `d,p` (or n for name, x for extension) is a subfield requirement.